# How to get a Wordpress Woocommerce products category tree with SQL with provided object_id, not via api?

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to find out a products "breadcrumb" if you will, the full category from root to last child. I know i need to subquery but i cannot make it work.

If i run these i can get it step by step but i need a single query to get the same result.

For example an iPhone case will have "Products > Mobile > Mobile Accessories > Cases"

```
SELECT parent, name FROM wp_term_relationships 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='product_cat') 
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id=wp_term_taxonomy.term_id ) 
WHERE object_id='2051'
```

The above code will give the products parent term_taxonomy_id (423) and categoryname: "Case"

So the next query i use the id i got from the above:

```
SELECT parent, name FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_terms.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='product_cat') 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '423'
```

Will give me a new parent id (412) and catecory name "Mobile Accessories"

So the next query i use the id i got from the above:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id=wp_terms.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy='product_cat') 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = '412'
```

This will as guessed give me name of parent category and so on.

I want to make only one SQL query with the object_id, so i can get the full tree, even if i dont know the depth of the current tree im in.

Answer (score 0):

Solution one is to return recursively only the first tree by using the following sql:

```
WITH RECURSIVE breadcrumb_cte AS (
  -- Base query
  SELECT 
    tt.term_taxonomy_id,
    tt.parent, 
    t.name, 
    0 AS depth,
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE parent = tt.term_taxonomy_id) AS is_leaf
  FROM wp_term_relationships tr
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  WHERE tr.object_id = <PRODUCT-ID>
  
  UNION ALL
  
  -- Recursive query
  SELECT 
    bc.term_taxonomy_id,
    tt.parent,
    t.name,
    bc.depth + 1 AS depth,
    bc.is_leaf
  FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  INNER JOIN breadcrumb_cte bc ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = bc.parent
  WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
)

SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY depth DESC SEPARATOR ' > ') AS breadcrumb
FROM breadcrumb_cte
WHERE is_leaf
GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id;
```

If you don't want to use the recursive method, but a cleaner one, you can use the following:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' > ', t4.name, t3.name, t2.name, t1.name) AS breadcrumb
FROM wp_term_relationships tr
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt1 ON tt1.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tt1.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
INNER JOIN wp_terms t1 ON t1.term_id = tt1.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt2 ON tt2.term_taxonomy_id = tt1.parent
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t2 ON t2.term_id = tt2.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt3 ON tt3.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.parent
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t3 ON t3.term_id = tt3.term_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt4 ON tt4.term_taxonomy_id = tt3.parent
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t4 ON t4.term_id = tt4.term_id
WHERE tr.object_id = <PRODUCT-ID>
AND (t4.name IS NOT NULL OR t3.name IS NOT NULL OR t2.name IS NOT NULL OR tt1.parent = 0)
ORDER BY tt4.term_taxonomy_id DESC, tt3.term_taxonomy_id DESC, tt2.term_taxonomy_id DESC, tt1.term_taxonomy_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Solution two is somekind problematic, I need help with that. You can return all category trees but also returns the partial trees that is duplicate of the full tree. You can correct that with php or correct directly the sql code but I don't have time to check it:

```
WITH RECURSIVE breadcrumb_cte AS (
  -- Base query
  SELECT 
    tt.term_taxonomy_id,
    tt.parent, 
    t.name, 
    0 AS depth
  FROM wp_term_relationships tr
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  WHERE tr.object_id = <PRODUCT-ID>
  
  UNION ALL
  
  -- Recursive query
  SELECT 
    bc.term_taxonomy_id,
    tt.parent,
    t.name,
    bc.depth + 1 AS depth
  FROM wp_term_taxonomy tt
  INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
  INNER JOIN breadcrumb_cte bc ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = bc.parent
  WHERE tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
)

SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY depth DESC SEPARATOR ' > ') AS breadcrumb
FROM breadcrumb_cte
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = (
  SELECT term_taxonomy_id 
  FROM wp_term_relationships tr
  INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
  WHERE tr.object_id = 507588
)
GROUP BY term_taxonomy_id;
```